# Result from mongoose query unavailable in parent scope

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to javascript and node and am having trouble returning the result from a mongoose query to an object I can work with.  My app currently parses the body of a post request into cache, uses a field in the cached object (mlcRecord.existFixture) to query the database, and returns an object from which to grab additional properties.  This part of the code works fine.  However, the additional properties are undefined outside of the .then scope.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic so any guidance folks can provide is appreciated.

```
router.route('/mlc')
.post(function (req,res){
   var mlcRecord = new mlcInputObj(req.body);
   async.series([
      function (callback) {
        function setWattages(mlcRecord) {

        // load the existFixture TechnologyID
        ltgTechnologies.findOne({TechnologyID: mlcRecord.existFixture}).exec()

        // capture the technologyID 
            .then(function(ltgTechnology){
                mlcRecord.existFixtureWatts = ltgTechnology.SystemWatts;
                return mlcRecord;
            });
        }

        setWattages(mlcRecord);

        console.log('mlcRecord: ', mlcRecord);  // existFixtureWatts displays as undefined
        callback();
     }
   ], function (err) {
    res.json(mlcRecord);
   });
});
```

Comment: can You put whole of file from Your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overcomplicated.

`async.series` not suitable for Your purpose.

Here is fix:

```
router
  .route('/mlc')
  .post(function (req,res){
    var mlcRecord = new mlcInputObj(req.body);

    // load the existFixture TechnologyID
    ltgTechnologies
      .findOne({TechnologyID: mlcRecord.existFixture})
      .exec(function(err, result) {
        mlcRecord.existFixtureWatts = null;
        if(result) {
          mlcRecord.existFixtureWatts = result.SystemWatts;
        }
        res.send(mlcRecord);
      });
  });
```

but if You want to save `mlcRecord` to database:

```
router
  .route('/mlc')
  .post(function (req,res){

    var mlcRecord = new mlcInputObj(req.body); // creating mlcRecord instance

    mlcRecord.save(function(err) { // inserting to database
      if(err) return res.status(500).send({err});

      // adding to mlcRecord  existFixtureWatts
      ltgTechnologies
        .findOne({TechnologyID: mlcRecord.existFixture})
        .exec(function(err, result) {
          mlcRecord.existFixtureWatts = null;
          if(result) {
            mlcRecord.existFixtureWatts = result.SystemWatts;
          }
          res.send(mlcRecord);
        });
    });

  });
```

Comment: Thank you @num8er.  After testing your solution I found it wont work for my purpose.  As I'm building a data pipeline based on the mlcRecord, I actually need async.waterfall.  It turns out that the issue I was having was related to .execution context.  I've put my solution as a comment below for anyone interested in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure exactly what the problem was with the execution context, but it seems that mlcRecord inside the promise returned by ltgTechnologies.findOne was not accessible outside the promise.   Returning the promise immediately in the setWattages function, then binding the resultant promise, solved my issue.  I also renamed a few fields and moved to function to a module.  Code below.

app.js

```
// some code ...
router
.route('/mlc')
.post(function (req,res){

var mlcRecord = new mlcInputObj(req.body);

async.waterfall([

    function (callback) {
        mlcRecord.setOccSensorScenario();
        mlcRecord.setltgTechnologyVals().then(function(){
            callback(null);
        });
    }, 
    // more functions to execute sequentially

], function (err, result) {
    res.json(mlcRecord);
});
});
// some other code ...
```

mlcInputObj.js (constructor)

```
// constructor
// ... 
// constructor methods

mlcInputObj.prototype.setltgTechnologyVals = function () {
//alias for 'this' used in bind
var mlcObj = this;

// load the existFixture TechnologyID
return Promise.all([
    // query ltgTechnologies and set existFixtureWatts
    ltgTechnologies.findOne({TechnologyID: this.existFixture}).exec()
    .then((function(fixture){
        this.existFixtureWatts = fixture.SystemWatts;
    }).bind(mlcObj)),
    // another promise,
    // last promise
]};
}
```